# Pydev; How Do I Config *all* .py To NOT Run In Ant?

Tags: eclipse, ant, pydev

Beginner config question here, guys.

So I am in eclipse, in pydev. Some of my src will run in the python compiler just fine, but others try and run in ant. When I click the 'Run' dropdown in the ones that work, and select 'Run As' I get two options. 'Python Run' and 'Python Unit-test'. When I try and run the ones that try and use Ant, I goto the same menu and it only displays '*(none applicable)*'

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem. If you were,like me, trying to run code that you had written in IDLE and saved somewhere. You have to create blank project and import that code into the "src" folder of your project. then you should be able to run the code as python in eclipse.
For example. I had a bit of code I was trying out in IDLE saved in a folder in "My Docs". I moved it to my project "src" folder in "Mydocs/eclipse/projects/" and was able to run it in eclipse. Your paths will depend on where you opted to save your eclipse projects.
You should then be able to select your "Python: run option.
This was the link that helped me with this.
http://www.vogella.com/articles/Python/article.html#installation_python

Read the whole thing and it should help.